# ¿Cómo puedo modificar mi CSS con javascript con un botón y que no se borre mi cambio al actualizar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo un menú de configuración y necesito que al pulsar un botón se modifique el CSS el cual le cambia el color a los botones y la imagen de fondo a varias páginas, pero al momento de cambiar de página o refrescar el cambio no se queda.
¿Hay alguna forma de actualizar el CSS desde el javascript o PHP para que se guarden los cambios y que al entrar de nuevo todo esté como es orignalmente?
Lo estoy cambiando de esta forma.

```
function change(){
    $('#backgroundImg').attr('background','img/maru.png');
    $('#backgroundImg').attr({src: 'img/maru.png'});
    var conf= $('#backBtn').css('background-color', 
    'rgb(32,32,250)');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes guardar localmente tus cambios en con `window.localStorage.setItem('nombre', valor)` y cada vez que cargue la pagina tomar esos valores y cargarlos con `window.localStorage.getItem('nombre')`

por ejemplo

```
function change(){
    var colorACambiar = 'rgb(32,32,250)';
    var imagenACambiar = 'img/maru.png';
    $('#backgroundImg').attr('background', imagenACambiar);
    $('#backgroundImg').attr({src: imagenACambiar});
    var conf= $('#backBtn').css('background-color', colorACambiar);

    window.localStorage.setItem('imagen', imagenACambiar)
    window.localStorage.setItem('color', colorACambiar)
}
```

y en el siguiente código lo utilizas cuando cargue toda la pagina (obviamente tienes que tomar sus valores para poder cambiar los botones, pero eso se lo dejo a usted)

```
window.localStorage.getItem('imagen')
window.localStorage.getItem('color')
```

buena suerte!!

Comment: Buena respuesta igual un poco de código y explicación no esta de mas

Comment: gracias! donde mando llamar el window.localStorage.getItem('nombre')? tengo el html, javascript y el css en archivos diferentes

Comment: en los archivos js tienes que llamarlo con algún evento onload o onready